# Create div at the same position of image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made an image slider. On click of an image I am dynamically creating a `div` with some text. In the onClick event of the image, I have added a `div` to the image, and then the image is flipped and `div` should be visible. But the image is appearing to the very right side of the page. How do I give it the same position as the image position?

This code I am using to a create `div` and then add an image to it:

```
function flipIt(obj){
    //$(obj).wrap("<div class='centerImage'></div>")

    console.log("value before Function status   "+status);

    $(obj).wrap($('<div class="foobar"/>').css({
        "position" : "absolute",
        "left"     : $(obj).position().left,
        "top"      : $(obj).position().top,
        "height"   :$(obj).height(),
        "width"    :$(obj).width(),
    }));
    $
    alert('classes ..'+$(obj).hasClass("foobar").toString());
    $(obj).animate({"left": "-=40px","opacity": "0.65"},"slow");
    $(obj).animate({"height":"600px","width":"320px"},30);

    $(obj).css("-webkit-backface-visibility","hidden");
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
    $(obj).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(obj).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");

    $(obj).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
    $(obj).css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
    //$(obj).css("box-shadow","-5px 5px 5px #aaa");

    status=0;
    console.log("after if value set status   "+status);
}
```

CSS property of .foobar div:

```
.foobar
{
    -webkit-backface-visibility:visible;
    position:absolute;
    color:red;
    background-color: red;
    background:red;
    content: div is here;
    height:450px;
    width:250px;
}
```

How do I bring the `div` on the position of that selected `img`?

Comment: try .foobar { top:0; left:0; .... }

Comment: can you add your HTML or a fiddle link for the same?

Comment: `$(obj).appendTo('foobar');` - this does not look right, you're appending to an element `<foobar>`

Comment: @MMM i have updated code now image div is dynamically created on same position as image but image is moved to left . i want div and image on same position.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir code updated. now problem is due to same position image is moved to left side.i applied absolute to selected image still its not working

Answer (score 0):

`$("#id").html("<div class='foobar'>This is div</div>")`
Give the id name of the div in which the image is present

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 $("#id").wrap('<div class="foobar"/>');
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/RQ62f/2/)